# Varnish "FetchError no backend connection" error

Tags: linux

Varnishlog:

```
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829925 1.0
   12 SessionOpen  c 79.124.74.11 3063 :80
   12 SessionClose c EOF
   12 StatSess     c 79.124.74.11 3063 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829928 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829931 1.0
   12 SessionOpen  c 108.62.115.226 46211 :80
   12 ReqStart     c 108.62.115.226 46211 467185881
   12 RxRequest    c GET
   12 RxURL        c /
   12 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.0
   12 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)
   12 RxHeader     c Host: www.mysite.com
   12 VCL_call     c recv lookup
   12 VCL_call     c hash
   12 Hash         c /
   12 Hash         c www.mysite.com
   12 VCL_return   c hash
   12 VCL_call     c miss fetch
   12 FetchError   c no backend connection
   12 VCL_call     c error deliver
   12 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   12 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   12 TxStatus     c 503
   12 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
   12 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   12 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 418
   12 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   12 TxHeader     c Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 20:45:31 GMT
   12 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 467185881
   12 TxHeader     c Age: 1
   12 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   12 Length       c 418
   12 ReqEnd       c 467185881 1340829931.192433119 1340829931.891024113 0.000051022 0.698516846 0.000074035
   12 SessionClose c error
   12 StatSess     c 108.62.115.226 46211 1 1 1 0 0 0 256 418
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829934 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1340829937 1.0
```

---

```
netstat -tlnp
 Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1915/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1279/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3195/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1914/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1317/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1192/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3195/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3072/memcached  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3086/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1915/varnishd   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1279/sshd
```

---

/etc/nginx/site-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen   8080; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:8080 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc {
        root /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.2;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root /usr/share;
        autoindex off;
    }

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.2:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

---

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.mysite.com.vhost

```
server {
       listen 8080;
       server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com.net;
       root /var/www/www.mysite.com/web;
       if ($http_host != "www.mysite.com") {
                 rewrite ^ http://www.mysite.com$request_uri permanent;
       }
       index index.php index.html;
       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }
       # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
       rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.2:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       }

include /var/www/www.mysite.com/web/nginx.conf;
       location ~ /nginx.conf {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

}
```

---

```
/etc/varnish/default.vcl

# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.2";
    .port = "8080";
    # .connect_timeout = 600s;
    #.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    # .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    # .max_connections = 800;
```

---

Note: uncommenting the last four options at default.vcl made no difference.

---

cat /etc/default/varnish

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "yes" to enable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

# Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with
# the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.
INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#              -T localhost:6082 \
#        -b localhost:8080 \
#        -u varnish -g varnish \
#            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#        -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a 1GB
# fixed-size cache file.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T 127.0.0.2:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

If you need any other info let me know. I am all out of clue as to whats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to verify whether or not you can connect to the backend manually. Try running the following command on the machine itself to determine whether the problem is with Apache or Varnish.:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.2:8080/
```